Filter entries by tags
I have two tables with a relationship
class Patient(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "patient"
    id = db.Column(db.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, server_default=sql.text("gen_random_uuid()"))
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    tags = db.relationship('PatientTag', backref="patient", lazy="dynamic")


class PatientTag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "patient_tag"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    patient_id = db.Column(db.UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey(Patient.id))
    mainTag = db.Column(db.String)
    subTag = db.Column(db.String)

I want to get all patients that have a specific tag, for example:
--Table Patient
id|name
--------
1 |pt a
2 |pt b
3 |pt c

--Table PatientTag
patient_id|mainTag|subTag
-------------------------
1         |spine  |
1         |spine  |degenerative
2         |spine  |trauma
3         |spine  |trauma

I want all patients with tag (spine, trauma) which will give me patient 2 and 3
or all patients with tag (spine, degenerative) which will give me patient 1 only

To query all patients who have a specific tag, you can join using the ForeignKey and then filter by tag.
main_tag = 'spine'
sub_tag = 'trauma'
patients = Patient.query\
    .join(PatientTag, PatientTag.patient_id == Patient.id)\
    .filter(PatientTag.mainTag == main_tag, PatientTag.subTag == sub_tag)\
    .all()
print(patients)

